# How to read and write password protected excel file?

Tags: excel, passwords, edit, protected

would you anyone know how to  read and write password protected excel file, in which i have password but PHPExcel not supported.

On the street, I find some hint on COM and .net , may anyone can provide some example on that use, else any other better method.

Please helpT.T!

Answer (score 0):

What SDK are you using?

According to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/openspecification/archive/2009/07/17/overview-of-protected-office-open-xml-documents.aspx) the Open XML SDK cannot open password protected files because of the format used.